# Prove the tautology (⋀( → ¬)) → ¬

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I must prove this tautology using logical equivalences but I can't quite figure it out. I know it has something to do with the fact that not p and p have opposite truth values at all times. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $p\to\neg q$ as $q\to\neg p$ (both are equivalent to $\neg p\lor\neg q$).

Comment: So then I'm thinking I do something along the lines of

 (⋀( → ¬)) → ¬p

(⋀( → ¬ )) → ¬p

( → ¬) → ¬p

I'm not sure if this is correct and I don't really know where to go from here. I'm very new to the whole subject.

Comment: @NarutoAbidal It'd be wiser to write something like $(q\land(p\to\neg q))\iff (q\land(q\to\neg p))\implies\neg p$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $p \rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow \neg p \lor q$

Applied to your statement:

$(q \land (p \rightarrow \neg )) \rightarrow \neg p \Leftrightarrow$

$\neg (q \land (p \rightarrow \neg )) \lor \neg p \Leftrightarrow$

$\neg q \lor \neg (p \rightarrow \neg ) \lor \neg p \Leftrightarrow$

$\neg q \lor \neg (\neg p \lor \neg ) \lor \neg p \Leftrightarrow$

$\neg q \lor (p \land q) \lor \neg p \Leftrightarrow$

$((\neg q \lor p) \land (\neg q \lor q)) \lor \neg p \Leftrightarrow$

$((\neg q \lor p) \land \top) \lor \neg p \Leftrightarrow$

$(\neg q \lor p) \lor \neg p \Leftrightarrow$

$\neg q \lor p \lor \neg p$

... and now you're almost there ... do you see it?

Comment: Continuing from this I did

p ∨ (¬q ∨ q) ∨ ¬p

p ∨ T ∨ ¬p

T

Would this be correct, or at least close to correct.

Comment: @NarutoAbidal No ..... not sure where you got that $p$ from ... did you try to do a DeMorgan on $\neg(\neg p \lor \neg q)$?  If so, you get $p \color{red} \land q$!  That is, you get $\neg q \lor (p \land q) \lor \neg q$.  But on that you can do a Distribution. Try again?

Comment: why did the last letter become q when it was p before?

Comment: @NarutoAbidal Sorry, typo!  Yes, that should be a $p$

Comment: From that point I'm thinking I need to get to q or not q as this will always be true yet there is at least one step in between I can't determine

Comment: @NarutoAbidal Try Distribution ... I'll add something to my answer